# Is there a best practice for word choice on resumes?

Tags: resume

When I was taught how to write resumes they say write to use lot of adjectives, i.e.

> Teamed with engineers to develop software application

To me it seems artificial, why not say

> Worked with a team to develop software application

What advantages are their to using one verbiage over the other?  Is there a better way to word my resume?

Comment: @MattGiltaji so you are saying the second description is more acceptable? Because to me it sounds natural. If I was hiring someone, I want them to be authentic, only then I can trust the quality of their work

Comment: I would have said that first is ungrammatical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say neither are very good for use on a resume as neither of them say what *you* did.

> Teamed with engineers to develop software application
>
> Worked with a team to develop software application

The IT staff who setup their desktops worked with engineers to developer a software application, the secretary who filed their expense reports as teamed with them too.

**Your resume is about *you*, not your team or your projects.** Its not thetime for modesty, put the focus squarely on *you*:

> Designed widgets for a large scale banking software application that improved performance by 20%.

**Wow!** Now you've said what you did, why you did it, and why your work was important. Be clear, be concise and always keep the focus on you.

Answer (score 3):

First, I'm not seeing any additional adjectives in the first version of the sentence.  Actually adding extra adjectives would not generally be a good idea.  Sentences in a resume should be active, quantified, and short.  Including extra adjectives would obviously make the sentences longer and frequently makes the sentences less active.

I suspect the contrast you are trying to ask about is between a sentence that is more active rather than more passive (many people talk about "active voice" and "passive voice" but their "passive voice" examples for resumes generally aren't actually "passive voice" in the English grammar sense).  For example, rather than saying

> Worked with a team to develop software application

it would generally be better to use a more active construction

> Delivered software application with a team of local and offshore developers.

or

> Contributed to the development of a new application that increased CSR productivity by 15% by streamlining the order entry process.

Your resume is a marketing document.  As such, it needs to quickly capture the reader's attention and it needs to emphasize the things that you actually accomplished.  The people reading your resume are going to spend 30-60 seconds in most cases skipping through what you've written.  You need to ensure that what you've written grabs their attention.

Of course, most people don't write or talk this way in general.  Often times, that's unfortunate-- the vast majority of business communication would be improved if people spent time making sentences more active (and working to eliminate extra words and working to come up with more concise summaries, etc.)  But most people don't have (or want to spend) the time required to do that with every email they send.  The fact that you have the time and incentive to optimize the way you communicate information in your resume doesn't make your resume inauthentic any more than optimizing a piece of code makes your normal, less efficient code inauthentic.  Both are your authentic style, one just happens to be something that you've invested more time than normal to perfect.